# Margin-left displayed different in Chrome than in IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, margin

I have an issue; In Chrome, I added margin-left: 4% to the left in the button menu, but in IE, the margin-left: 4% is a bit too big, it moves everything too much to the right. Do you know what the issue might be? You have the images below.

**Chrome picture:**
[image: Chrome picture]

**IE picture:**
[image: IE picture]

Comment: The text looks different on the IE picture... what font are you using, did you specify font-size, font-family.. did you specify letter spacing? what about font-weight? also, did you check in the developer tools, if there is any additional padding/margin or anything in the elements that can cause this? how about some code????

Comment: I can only help you as much as you let me help you. That is insufficient data for anyone here to extrapolate on. You could have an error in your code somewhere. But as it looks on the images you provided, something must be wrong with the font. (as they are displayed differently too, look at the icons, it's clearly visible there)

Comment: The elements is called .navigationButtons and has the following properties: margin-left: 4%; font-family: Raleway, font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;

Comment: Yes I think you were right! I think is has to do with the font-family: Raleway. Maybe it is not displayed properly in IE. I deleted that and everything looks fine